# Migration from Flash CS3 to CS5: TextField rendering problem

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an Actionscript project that was building using Flash cs3.
Project have TextFields (Text engine: classic text, Text type: dynamic text).
Since I upgraded to CS5 and published, I find out that my text not rendered.
I use Font family Tahoma. And I just set Font family to Tahoma again and published. After that manipulations my text start render.
But when somebody else try to open my project using same Flash CS5 IDE and just published that project again without any modification - none of my text is rendered again. And that going round in circles.
Any ideas how to fix this problem?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its an issue with either the new TLF TextFields in CS5 or a matter of embedding your fonts.

Try doing the following:

1) Select your TextField in flash and go to the text properties. In there right underneath where you set the texts instance name, should be a drop down menu showing TLF Text. Select Classic Text from the drop-down instead.

2) Where you select your font family, there should be a button called Embed. Click it and select all the characters of that font family you want to embed.

If all else fails, just create a new TextField in CS5 and replace the old one with it. Flash can act a bit weird at times.

Answer (score 0):

Fox, thanks for your advice but this not help.

To fix this problem I did following:

1) Select **Classic Text**.

2) Font rendering method: set Anti-alias to **Use device fonts**.